# Queuing the entire Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have three jobs in my jenkins pipeline. The requirement is to queue the pipeline, ie, it should run as it is for the first build; for the second build (before the first gets completed), the flow should be - get all the 3 jobs done from the first build, then go for the second build.
PS: Is it possible through Build Blocker plugin? If so, how?

Comment: Also, I do not have admin privileges to jenkins.

Comment: Question is not elaborate, please add more information on job tree , sequence of execution expected.

Comment: I have a pipeline having 3 jobs, say, A, B, C. which will run in sequence. When I run the pipeline twice, it should follow the sequence like:
for the first run - A, B, C. Then after that for the second run - A, B, C.
These pipeline take an hour or so to run. While running the first pipeline, if I again run the pipeline for the second time, the jobs A, B, C (for the second pipeline) should get queued.
Am i clear now?

Comment: Are these `freestyle` jobs or `pipeline` jobs? I am almost sure that for either of them the execution sequences can never overlap because of the fact that they are running based on the jenkins builds timers and the build time of each job is always going to be almost the same so they will fall under a implicit and natural queueing mechanism. The only way would be to create a test pipeline and trigger `job A` around 10 times and then compare the build timestamps of the `10*3 executions` to see if there was any incorrect sequence.

Comment: I am using build blocker plugin to block the jobs- A/B/C, if any of the jobs - A/B/C is running. On the second run, i am getting concurrent execution of the first job - A. ( Scenario applied: while job A is running on first run, I re run the pipeline, so again I have two jobs A and A, running simultaneously.
I don't know about the kind of jobs but they are simple build, deploy, 'run some more stuff', kinda jobs.

Comment: I am starting to think it is not a good idea in this scenario, to have these 3 as separate jobs. If you demand sequential execution why cant you put all the stages into a single pipeline job. That would solve the problem.

Comment: This is a good question that I would like to have an answer as well.
The Block Build Plugin is not entirely converted to Pipeline Groovy code.
Even if you use the Jenkins Code Snippet generator it will create a `properties` block which is not supported. And the `options` block does not support the Build Block Class.